# iOS 8 get notification when UITextView Predictive is enabled/disabled

Tags: ios, ios8

Is it possible to receive a local notification when Predictive is enable/disabled.

I have a `UITextView` and when Predictive is enabled, the `inputAccessoryView` of this `textView` moves up and it hides the last line in `textView`. If its possible to get notification that Predictive has changed, I can resize the `textView`.

I searched but could not find any way to receive the notification.

I also did not find any delegate methods for this in `UITextViewDelegate`.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not move up little bit your view when you start typing and solved this issue :)?
Use UITextFieldDelegate and  use this code (you can animate this if you want)

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
    rect.origin.y = - 30; //enter pixels number to pushup your view 
    self.view.frame = rect;

}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
    rect.origin.y = 0; //return to 0.0 position.
    self.view.frame = rect;
}
```

Comment: i answered in objective C but just use in func instead methods

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to listen to the notifications received from `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`?

Comment: These notifications are for Keyboard showing/hiding. My question is about when predictive text enables/disables.

Comment: By enabling/disabling, do you mean swiping the control up and down? If so, those keyboard notifications will tell you if the predictive bar is visible or not (gives you the rect).